# Regex to remove part of a string

Tags: regex, autoblogged

Here is my string `http://www.example.com/dl/r66h5icmsyrh`

I need to remove `http://www.example.com/dl/`

I am using autoblogged a wordpress plugin; which can handle regex in post template

This is what i tried.

```
%regex("%link%", "http://www.example.com/dl/", "0")%
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
%regex("%link%", "\\([^\\]+)$\", "0")%
```

Comment: Yes, i do. Autoblogged template only allows for it. http://autoblogged.com/support/online-manual/advanced-usage/post-template-reference/

Comment: Try this then, for your regex

Comment: ([^\\]+)$   Should grab everything after the last \

Comment: %regex("%link%",([^\]+)$)    - Would this work; %link% is the dynamic link from autoblogged.

Comment: the regex pattern needs to be in quotes.

Comment: I'll try %regex("%link%","([^]+)$")

Comment: %regex("%link%", "\([^\]+)$\", "0")% didn't work i get the following error in autoblogged: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /home/content/46/8529846/html/wp-content/plugins/autoblogged_2-8-51/autoblogged.php at line 2654

I only got that error when i tried using the regex

Comment: Apparently, that delimiter doesn't work.  Try using a hashtag/number sign (#) for the delimiter ---> #([^\]+)$#